# Simulators/emulators for mobile browser testing on ubuntu / linux

Tags: linux, browser, mobile, emulation, device-emulation

I'm building the mobile version of a website and I want a way to test it.
The problem with a lot of free emulators is that they are for windows.
I know I could run them in wine, just wondering if there are native GNU/Linux applications.

PS: I want to perform these tests locally, I'm not looking for online emulators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/1.6_r1/index.html

I know android has a emulator for linux development I am sure you could use that. I have not used it myself much.

Comment: Maybe this was a good option at the time, but the Android emulator is an insanely heavy-handed solution. You don't need to emulate a browser  running on an OS on a hardware emulator. Just use the browser you're already using.

Answer (score 13):

Install Opera Mobile in Ubuntu (.deb)

it´s faster then the Android-emulators, so better for Web-apps dev.

[image]

Opera Labs have made installation in Ubuntu super easy:

1. You download [this .deb](http://www.opera.com/download/get.pl?sub=%20%20%20%20&id=32823&location=270&nothanks=yes)
2. Double-click on it once download has completed
3. Click on 'Install' in Ubuntu Software Center.
4. Then open your ’Dash Home’ an wirte 'op'.

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/install-opera-mobile-in-ubuntu-deb

Answer (score 9):

Use mobile emulation mode in Chrome:
[image]

See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#enable-device-mode

Comment: "Toggle the Device Mode button (near upper-left of developer tools) to turn Device Mode on or off."

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of emulators here: http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators

Answer (score 2):

The [GnuPoc](http://gnupoc.sourceforge.net/) project provides a SymbianOS SDK for GNU/Linux. Check out the [Symbian development on Linux and OS X](http://www.martin.st/symbian/) page too.